# Do I have to create a MEW wallet to transfer ETH from Metamask to Trezor?

Tags: myetherwallet, metamask, trezor

I have a Metamask wallet with ETH in it. I want to move these ETH to my Trezor. It appears that Trezor will only accept ETH via MEW. Do I need to create a MEW wallet and move everything in two steps, first from Metamask to MEW and then from MEW to Trezor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addresses do not prevent ETH being sent to them, that is of course, unless they’re smart contracts specifically coded to receive ETH only under certain conditions, which hardware wallets are not.  Hardware wallets just generate standard (not smart contract) Ethereum wallet addresses.

You just need to use the wallet address generated from your Trezor and send ETH to that.

If not convinced, try sending a small test amount first, eg 0.01 ETH, and confirm it is received.